# What is python's equivalent of the View() dataframe command?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, variable-dump

I am just beginning to learn python for data science tasks in my day job.

I use spyder as python IDE that comes with anaconda.
And i am trying to learn efficient ways to explore dataframe objects.

As a user of R with RStudio i very much like the View() command that shows a dataframe in a separate window in a spreadsheet style that allows to filter and sort the data.

Here is what i mean in R / RStudio:

instead of viewing the iris dataframe like this:

```
> iris
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
...
```

i would like to view the the data like this

```
View(iris)
```

[image]

Is there any command or specific package in python or specific python IDE that provides such funcionality?

Answer (score 3):

[There's an open feature request to this effect](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5137) so I guess there's no *direct* equivalent atm.

You can view a Dataframe as table via variable explorer as per [How to get to last record of large dataframe in Spyder window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547818/how-to-get-to-last-record-of-large-dataframe-in-spyder-window). In Jupyter (another Python IDE, primarily designed for `scipy`), there are other functions with the same effect as per [Show DataFrame as table in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/show-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook).